# Are algebraic groups defined over $\mathbb{R}$ Lie groups?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, algebraic-groups

In the notes I am reading, which is about algebraic groups, in the section about over $\mathbb{R}$ all the sudden they started using the word Lie groups. I understand Lie groups and algebraic groups are related but I am finding this section of the notes confusing.

If I have $G$ a linear algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ say, and if I consider $G(\mathbb{R})$ the real points, does it automatically become a Lie group (with the Zariski topology)?

Comment: The Zariski topology is not Hausdorff, so we do not have a Lie group.

Comment: More generally, the Zariski topology is way too coarse for analytic endeavours

Comment: A connected linear algebraic group is a Lie group in the Euclidean topology. I think only a finite group would be a Lie group in the Zariski topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $G$ is a linear algebraic group over $\mathbb{R}$, (it is automatically smooth and) $G(\mathbb{R})$ can be viewed as a polynomial subset of some affine space $\mathbb{R}^n$. For the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and not the Zariski topology), $G(\mathbb{R})$ is a smooth sub-manifold, and since the multiplication and inverse on $G(\mathbb{R})$ are given by polynomials, they are smooth, so $G(\mathbb{R})$ is a real Lie group in the sens of differential geometry. But I think there are real Lie groups that don't come this way.

It is the same thing for complex algebraic linear groups.

Comment: (+1) Two things. First, there are Lie groups that don't come this way (e.g. the universal cover of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. Secondly, note that $G(\mathbb{R})$ being even relatively well-behaved is hard. For example, the fact that $G(\mathbb{R})$ has finitely many connected components is not even obvious!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One of the things I'm still not getting is how one puts Euclidean topology on $G(\mathbb{R})$... The points of linear algebraic groups correspond to prime ideals of some ring (at least in this notes I'm reading). The maximal ideals correspond to the "actual points" in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I think, so what happens to the other points? How do you put Euclidean topology when $G(\mathbb{R})$ contains "other points"? (or do we just ignore the points that do not correspond to maximal ideals for this purpose of viewing it as a Lie group?)

Comment: Writing $G$ as $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[X_1,\cdots,X_n]/(P_1,\cdots,P_m))$ ($G$ is a closed subvariety of an affine space), the set of $\mathbb{R}$-points of $G$ is $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{R}-alg}(\mathbb{R}[X_1,\cdots,X_n]/(P_1,\cdots,P_m), \mathbb{R})$ which can be identified with $\lbrace x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \, | \, P_1(x)=\cdots=P_n(x)=0 \rbrace \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: $\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$If $A$ is a commutative $\RR$-algebra and $X = \text{Spec}(A)$, then $X(\RR)$ is the set of $\RR$-algebra homomorphisms from $A$ to $\RR$. Each $f \in A$ can be thought of as a function $X(\RR) \to \RR$, and we topologize $X(\RR)$ by taking as a basis of open sets $\{ x \in X(\RR) : |f(x)| < \epsilon \}$ for $f \in A$ and $\epsilon > 0$. If $A = \RR[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]/(p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_m)$, then  $X(\RR)$ is the solutions to $p_1=p_2=\cdots=p_m=0$ in $\RR^n$, with the topology induced from the Euclidean topology on $\RR^n$.

Comment: For example, if $A = \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2+y^2-1)$, then $X(\mathbb{R})$ is the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, with its usual topology. The fact that $A$ has maximal ideals that don't correspond to points of $X(\mathbb{R})$ (for example $\langle x-2, y^2+3 \rangle$) is irrelevant.